# Can't send parameter containing "#" to dot net web service from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

Cant send parameter containing "#" to dot net web service from ajax.

```
var s = encodeURI(
    "http://subdomain.mydomain.domain.asmx/getData?OUserId=" + UserId +
    "&Token=" + Token +
    "&OrgId=" + OrgId +
    '&Message=' + Message +
    '&Schoolid=' + SchoolId +
    '&SessionId=" ' + SessionId +
    '&UnicodeValue=' + UnicodeValue +
    '&ClassID=' + ClassIdCommaSeparated.toString()
);

$.ajax({
    url: s,
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },
    success: function(data) {....
    }
});
```

Here classIdCommaSeparated is `1#1#1#1#1,1#1#1#1#1,1#1#1#1#1`.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: `encodeURI` does not encode `#`, you need to encode each parameter individually using `encodeURIComponent` in order to properly encode `#`

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you.

Comment: i have already tried to encode the parameter classid individually with encodeURIComponent  without any luck

Comment: ajax makes them double encoded.for example performing encodeURIComponent on  classidcomaseparated gives me a value  "1%231%231%231%23     and ajax once again encodes the modulus to "%25" ending with a result "1%25231%2523%2523%2523.sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 2):

Use `encodeURIComponent` on the individual parts, rather than `encodeURI` on the whole:

```
var s = "http://subdomain.mydomain.domain.asmx/getData?OUserId=" + encodeURIComponent(UserId) +
        "&Token=" + encodeURIComponent(Token) +
        "&OrgId=" + encodeURIComponent(OrgId) +
        '&Message=' + encodeURIComponent(Message) +
        '&Schoolid=' + encodeURIComponent(SchoolId) +
        '&SessionId=" ' + encodeURIComponent(SessionId) +
        '&UnicodeValue=' + encodeURIComponent(UnicodeValue) +
        '&ClassID=' + encodeURIComponent(ClassIdCommaSeparated.toString());

$.ajax({
    url: s,
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },
    success: function(data) {....
    }
});
```

Technically, both the name (before the `=`) and the value (after the `=`) need to be encoded, but when your names consist just of the letters A-Z (in upper or lower case) or digits, like yours do, encoding them doesn't change them at all. (If you didn't know what those names were, you'd definitely want to pass them through `encodeURIComponent`.)

Answer (score 0):

several hours after i am not able to understand what is arising this problem.but i have worked around to have a temporary solution to the problem.i have used underscore in place of # and i got it working.thanks @T.J. Crowder for having a look upon.